# How To Resize a Node Using Python script

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

I have created a node group 'test_group' using Python and now I want to resize my the node as it has much less width than I want that it to have.

Can anyone tell me how to do that using a Python script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the API, there is [`Node.height`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html?highlight=width#bpy.types.Node.height) as well as [`Node.width`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html?highlight=width#bpy.types.Node.width). Assign whatever float you like:

> Type:  float in [-inf, inf], default 0.0

API link: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html